# How to remove git related data from a git clone?

Tags: git, github

I want to clone a specific branch of a git repository and copy it to my own private git repository. The original repository is very huge and has a lot of branches, which I don't need at all. I also don't need any file history. Forking is not an option, because forked repositories are not allowed to be private on github.

After running

```
git clone https://example.com/repo.git -b my-branch
```

how can I get rid of all git-specific information in the local copy, keep only my-branch, as if I just created the contained files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply delete the `.git` directory and re-initialize the repository.

```bash
rm -rf .git # Delete all git information
git init # Recreate an empty repo
git add --all # Re-add all the files to the index
git commit -m 'Initial fork from example.com/repo.git'
```

Comment: My specific issue was apparently a second .git directory in a sub-directory. Thanks!